# RTL in iOS 9.2 issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, ios9.2

My following code was working for iOS 9.0 and iOS 9.1 but when I upgrade to 9.2 it is not working well.For support of older version, I am using CGAffineTransform.

```
if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"9.0"))
 {
   [[UIView appearance]setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight];
 }
```

Why this one is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't do this. You're not supposed to set the `semanticContentAttribute` on `UIAppearance` proxies.

Comment: Yes, thanks mate as now I know what will be the disadvantage with it.On every release i have to check again if the app is working with this tweak.Now following proper steps for my future release it will not be a worry.